# resp.text from requests.get() gives the attributes value as - - instead of actual value

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get the value of a particular field from a web page. The starter code I've is as follows:

```
import requests

def stocks():
    # the target we want to open
    url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp? 
           symbol=RELIANCE&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0'
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 
                              Firefox/66.0",
               "Accept-Encoding": "*", 
               "Connection": "keep-alive"}

    resp = requests.get(url,headers = headers)

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        print("Successfully opened the web page")
        print(resp.text)
    else:
        print("Error")


stocks()
```

I'm trying to obtain the value of a span with id **lowpriceBand**. But the output shows the value of this span as **--** instead of actual value **1051.25**:
[image: This is the screenshot of the output]
This is the case with other elements also.
But when I inspect the actual website in the browser I can see the value of 1051.25 as shown:
[image: Screenshot of browser with required element in blue]

I'm quite new to this so totally confused of why this is happening. Tried browsing about this, couldn't locate any relevant question. Thanks in advance

Comment: Those spans are probably populated by JS - which is not run when requests is fetching the page

Comment: I can confirm, after visiting the site myself,  the spans are filled using JS

Comment: You can get the raw json from that page. Chrome > developer tools > network. Filter by XHR and look for any url that contains data. You can inspect the data with preview